# pykml and utf8: either the input is incorrect, or I don't get it

Tags: python, utf-8, pykml

I have a kmz file from the www and wish to read it into csv or such using pykml.
The file is in UTF8, or at least it claims to - see header below. Reading it works, but triggers an error when coming on the first accented character.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
 <Document>
   <name>

from pykml import parser
with open(KMZFIL) as f:
 folder=parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder
for pm in folder.Placemark:
 print(pm.name)

Ablitas (militar) (Emerg)
Ademuz (forestal)
Ager (PL%)
Alcala del Rio (ILIPA MAGNA)(Esc.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin4/b21_xxxxxxx", line 15, in <module>
    print(pm.name)

grep "name" $INFIL | head -7
 ( ... )
   <name>Ablitas (militar) (Emerg)</name>
   <name>Ademuz (forestal)</name>
   <name>Ager (PL%)</name>
   <name>Alcala del Rio (ILIPA MAGNA)(Esc.)</name>
   <name>Ainzón</name>
```

Comment: Forgot to add what is actually in the input:     grep Ainz $INFIL | hexdump -C
    00000000  09 09 09 09 3c 6e 61 6d  65 3e 41 69 6e 7a c3 b3  |....<name>Ainz..|
00000010  6e 3c 2f 6e 61 6d 65 3e  0a                       |n</name>.|
00000019

Comment: Yes, that dump shows a UTF-8 character in the correct place. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: sorry, I should have added that too. python --version
Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in a way that instructs Python to interpret the bytes as UTF-8 characters. In Python 2.7 you do it with the [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html).

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(KMZFIL, encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

In Python 3 the `encoding` option has been added to the standard `open` so there's no need to use `codecs`.

Comment: Still no good, the same error at the same spot:    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bin4/b21_xxxxxxx", line 16, in <module>
       print(pm.name)
       UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
Besides, I always understood UTF-8 is the default, for all python file operations, why should I need to refer to it explicitly?

Comment: @KarelAdams no, UTF-8 is *not* the default - the default is given by [`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding). And I missed the part that your problem was in *printing* the result, sorry. That's a totally different answer that I don't have at the top of my head but should be available here on-site somewhere.

Comment: Actually it is for me to be sorry, I did not originally indicate the error was in the print statement. Where does the default encoding come from? Is it taken from some LC environment variable at python startup?

Comment: @KarelAdams you'll have to go searching for that information. I found one: https://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/05/14/python-how-is-sysstdoutencoding-chosen/

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that was enough to find me a solution. Well, that is to say, I consider it a work-ariound rather, but it does do the job. Also, I understand the issue will only present itself on writing to sdtout, which I only do for verification/debugging; the actual code will write to a file, so it shouldn't see this issue anyway.                                                              import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see the answer here but these are lmxl StringElements -- I used .text to fix this error.

change  print(pm.name) to print(pm.name.text)

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify.StringElement-class.html